# postfix dual delivery to local (virtual) mailbox and google smtp

Tags: postfix

We're migrating from our own mail server to Google Apps and I need to somehow deliver any incoming mail to both the local mail server and Google until we have everyone moved over. I'm following the instructions given at https://support.google.com/a/answer/9228551  using "Legacy server as primary server > Server-based forwarding" and I can get mail delivered either locally OR to Google using transport_maps but not both. Does anyone know how I can get mail delivered to both the local account and Google without making major changes to the current postfix setup?

Here's the output of postconf -n (minus stuff that's obviously not needed)

```
content_filter = scan:blocker.example.com:10025
inet_protocols = ipv4
message_size_limit = 15360000
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, mail.example.com
mynetworks = 1.1.1.0/24
mynetworks_style = host
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net, reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, check_helo_access hash:/data/config/helo_access
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_recipient_access ldap:/data/config/message.ldap, check_recipient_access hash:/data/config/recipient_checks, permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination, reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org, reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net, check_policy_service inet:blocker.example.com:10031
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = example.com
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, check_sender_access hash:/data/config/access, check_sender_access hash:/data/config/sender_checks, check_sender_access regexp:/data/config/sender_checks.regex, permit_mynetworks, reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net, reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_use_tls = yes
soft_bounce = no
transport_maps = hash:/data/config/transport
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
virtual_alias_domains =
virtual_alias_maps = ldap:/data/config/alias.ldap
virtual_gid_maps = static:125
virtual_mailbox_base = /data/mail
virtual_mailbox_domains = ldap:/data/config/domains.ldap
virtual_mailbox_maps = ldap:/data/config/mailbox.ldap
virtual_transport = virtual
virtual_uid_maps = static:125
```

Thank you!

Comment: Just curious. Did you find a solution? I'm trying to solve exactly the same task, but I cannot find a way how to tell postfix to deliver email locally and then deliver it again to Google.

I've found this article https://jyotishp.ml/tutorials/postfix/dual-delivery-for-postfix
but as far as I understand it requires 2 servers:

1 postfix delivers email locally and makes BCC to second "relay" server. And "relay" uses transport map to deliver copy to Google.

Comment: I used that same guide and it worked very well. It is unfortunate that you have to run two servers but that was the only way I could find to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I ended up following the steps given here: https://jyotishp.ml/tutorials/postfix/dual-delivery-for-postfix

It worked very well. Unfortunately, you do have to run two servers but I couldn't find any other way to do it.